How to solve a simultaneous equation with composite hidden variables $xx, xy, yy$?
Is there a general method for solving a system of simultaneous equations, where each term is always a composite product of 2 atomic variables, e.g.
$$xx - \frac{3}{7}xy + \frac{1}{7}yy = 0$$
$$xy - 7yy+20yz = 0$$
$$yz = 0$$
Is there a general method for solving this system of equations in terms of its atomic variables $x, y, z$?

Start with the last equation: $yz=0 \implies y=0$ or $z=0$. In the first case, the second equation is trivially satisfied and the first implies $x=0$. I leave for you the case $z=0$.

@Gonçalo thank you. For the above system, i have figured the solution as $x=0, y=0$ and $z$ being a free variable. How could we turn this into an algorithmic procedure, where there may not be an easy $yz=0$ hatch like the system above?

Is $xx$   the same thing as $x^2  ; ; ?  ; ; ; $

@WillJagy yes, $xx=x^2$

What is the domain of the variables $x,y,z$?  Integers?  Real numbers?  ${0,1}$?

@D.W. great answer! Yes, the variables are real numbers.

The question is clear and has a clear answer (which actually has been answered satisfactorily). As this is essentially a done question which is solved and no longer active, what can be the motive of someone visiting an old solved inactive question and spending energy trying to close it?

This is a system of quadratic equations.  Finding a solution is NP-hard.  (See, e.g., https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/79339/755.)  Therefore, you should not expect any general procedure that works in all cases and is efficient even as you increase the number of variables and equations.
If you want to find a solution in the real numbers, the problem is complete for the existential theory of the reals, i.e., $\exists \mathbb{R}$.  (See, e.g., https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/127282/755.)  Consequently, there are algorithms to solve the problem, but they take exponential time.  In practice, you can try using a computer algebra system.  (See also A general method for solving systems of quadratic equations, Solving systems of quadratic equations)
If you want to find a solution in the integers, the problem is undecidable.  In other words, there is no general algorithm.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/616704/14578.
If you want to find a solution over $\{0,1\}$, the problem is NP-complete and can be solved in practice with a SAT solver.

A quick follow up question please, suppose the terms are composite products of 4 instead of 2 atomic variables, e.g. $2wwxy-3wxxy+4wxyz+5xyyz+6yyyz = 0$ does this make the problem harder? Is there a classification/metric for how hard different NP-hard problems are?

@James, please don't use the comments to ask new questions.  If you have a question about systems of quartic equations, you should think hard about it based on the information provided here, and if you still can't make any progress, ask that via the 'Ask Question' button.  Please make sure to include the domain you want to find solutions in, and to ask only one question per post.

$$xx - \frac{3}{7}xy + \frac{1}{7}yy = 0$$
$$xy - 7yy+20yz = 0$$
$$yz = 0$$
or
$$   7 x^2 - 3 xy + y^2 = 0  , $$
$$(x-7y+20z) y = 0, $$
$$ y z = 0$$
The second and third  left-hand-sides   factor, giving choices.
The first equation can be dealt with by the quadratic formula  or by completing the square, which is a useful skill. With integers,  we can multiply $a x^2 + stuff$  by $4a,$  in the case $28$
$$   196 x^2 - 84 xy + 28y^2 = 0  , $$
$$  ( 14 x - 3y)^2 +  19 y^2 = 0$$
You said the variables were real, actually $y = 0$   and $14x - 3y=0$   so that $x=0$ also.
One may complete the square in the other variable,
$$   7 x^2 - 3 xy + y^2 = 0   $$
or
$$   28 x^2 - 12 xy + 4y^2 = 0   $$
$$  19 x^2 + (-3x + 2y)^2 = 0$$
same outcome.
So, the second and third equations are redundant.
